# Number of lines of code VS Number of instructions

Tags: coding-style, standards

I was wondering whether in computer science there is a best practice as to whether to favor number of line of code or number of instructions, when the 2 pull in different directions?

Example 1: the below code has less number of rows, but the if are assessed for every g, whereas they do not depend on g.

```
For g = 0 To UBound(myRegions)
    If Cells(2, j) = "" And Cells(myRowToBeAllocated, 4 + j) <> 0 Then
        Cells(2, g) = Worksheet("Test").Cells(k, q)
    ElseIf Cells(myRowToBeAllocated, 4 + j) <> 0 Then
        Cells(2, g) = Worksheet("Test").Cells(2 * k, q / 2)
    End If
Next g
```

Example 2: the below code has more rows, but the ifs are not assessed for every g, hence the below leads to less instructions being executed by the compute.

```
If Cells(2, j) = "" And Cells(myRowToBeAllocated, 4 + j) <> 0 Then
    For g = 0 To UBound(myRegions)
        Cells(2, g) = Worksheet("Test").Cells(k, q)
    Next g
ElseIf Cells(myRowToBeAllocated, 4 + j) <> 0 Then
    For g = 0 To UBound(myRegions)
        Cells(2, g) = Worksheet("Test").Cells(2 * k, q / 2)
    Next g
End If
```

The question is: is there a best practice with regard to which one is best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you are putting computing speed versus readability. In that case, there is not really a best practice, as it depends on the circumstances: for a small program that has to run as efficiently as possible, I'd go for option 2, as it is speed critical. For everything else (which is mostly the case for modern, fast computers), I would not put effort into speed optimization until it really is a problem. Much more important is that the code is readable and maintainable. The required work hours spent trying to understand some ugly code that runs fast are much more expensive than some hardware upgrade to make the code execute faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my company we work on laptop. The CPU standard in 2013 was i7-3635QM, but the standard now is i7-5500U which is slower. When I started writing the program I assumed that CPU speed was going to double every 18 month and that the task that took 3 minutes would get done faster. But this has not been the case, so I always struggle balancing speed versus code readability.